# Can a muslim girl take her education from a non-mahram male teacher?

Tags: practical-islam, sharia, education, knowing-islam

Can a muslim girl take her education in-person from a non-mahram muslim or non-muslim male teacher by attending his classroom? Here in my region this is norm and the parents and the girls doesn’t even care about Hijab; some teachers got fired from school because of their ill-lust to these teenage girls!!! So what's the ruling on this in Islam?

Answer (score 1):

Traditional fiqh advises girls to be tought by female teachers, with the possiblity of male teachers teaching them behind a curtain (see [here](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/135155/can-a-male-teacher-teach-a-female-in-class-or-privately/)).

[This fatwa](https://islamqa.org/maliki/binbayyah/29889/ruling-on-girls-studying-at-coed-schools-of-medicine/) says that it is allowable for female students to be taught by male teachers at university under the condition that there are no major incidents.

In your case, at least those teachers got fired, but morality may be a problem even in the scope of the more tolerant second fatwa.

Comment: Would be better to quote the brief/main part of the fatwa in your answer !